# SQL Server Round a DateTime to the nearest 5 seconds?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Just wondering if anyone can help me with this. I would like to round the SQL datetime to the nearest 5 seconds

For example the dates on the left should give me the following result on the right.

- 1900-01-01 14:08:20.000 -> 1900-01-01 14:08:20.000
- 1900-01-01 14:08:21.000 -> 1900-01-01 14:08:20.000
- 1900-01-01 14:08:22.000 -> 1900-01-01 14:08:20.000
- 1900-01-01 14:08:23.000 -> 1900-01-01 14:08:25.000
- 1900-01-01 14:08:24.000 -> 1900-01-01 14:08:25.000
- 1900-01-01 14:08:25.000 -> 1900-01-01 14:08:25.000

I have seen a similar solution for minute intervals and I have tried to apply it to seconds but it doesn't give the ideal result.

```
declare @DT datetime

set @DT = convert(datetime,'14:08:20')
select dateadd(s,(datepart(s,dateadd(s,1,@DT))/5)*5,
    dateadd(mi,datediff(mi,0,dateadd(s,1,@DT)),0))
```

However, 1900-01-01 14:08:23.000 gives me  1900-01-01 14:08:20.000,  which is not correct.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask what the goal is?  Are you doing grouping on the server for something?  It seems wasteful to have SQL chug away at this unless it's truly critical for the next step in some database-side process; otherwise I'd do it at the application level instead.

Comment: I agree but I can't think of any other way of doing it. Basically the requirement is as I mentioned round the dates to the nearest 5 seconds before it gets inserted into another table. The data is not used in code at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some usage of [DATEPART()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) and [ROUND()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx), you can achieve this

**Query**

```
declare @t table (dt datetime);

insert @t 
select
'1900-01-01 14:08:20.000' union all select
'1900-01-01 14:08:21.000' union all select
'1900-01-01 14:08:22.000' union all select
'1900-01-01 14:08:23.000' union all select
'1900-01-01 14:08:24.000' union all select
'1900-01-01 14:08:25.000';

select dt, 
       dateadd(second, round(datepart(second,dt)*2,-1) / 2-datepart(second,dt), dt)
from   @t
order by dt;
```

**Results:**

```
dt                      rounded
----------------------- -----------------------
1900-01-01 14:08:20.000 1900-01-01 14:08:20.000
1900-01-01 14:08:21.000 1900-01-01 14:08:20.000
1900-01-01 14:08:22.000 1900-01-01 14:08:20.000
1900-01-01 14:08:23.000 1900-01-01 14:08:25.000
1900-01-01 14:08:24.000 1900-01-01 14:08:25.000
1900-01-01 14:08:25.000 1900-01-01 14:08:25.000
```